# Querying data in firebase multiple Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to  display data in `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` where I have two queries returning true but I'm able to do for one.

```
adapterArchive = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bill, BillViewHolder>(Bill.class,
                    R.layout.bill_item,
                    BillViewHolder.class,
                    bill.orderByChild("date").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate)) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BillViewHolder viewHolder, Bill model, int position) {


                    viewHolder.txtBillNumber.setText("Number :  " + model.getNumber());
```

I want to display data which lie in the given date and in `populateViewHolder` I want to display only for`(model.getStatus() == 6)`. but it's not happening. Please help me out with this

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: As frank's comment, I would [fan-out](https://hackernoon.com/firebase-server-side-fan-out-722e825a05fb) original 'Bill' data to another path. It will be like this -> 'bill-status-6'. Or you could migrate to [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) which allow multiple queries.